# Naive Bayes Classifier in e1071 package [R] - Editing Data

Tags: r, classification

So I'm currently using the Naive Bayes classifier from the e1071 package to classify data, and I was wondering if there was any way to interact with, and edit the data.

For example, using the iris dataset, and the methods described [here](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~jc/teaching/arin/R_practical/) to extract a classifier from it, I want to be able to select the individual tables in the classifier.

I would like to be able to select a specific data table (such as the Sepal.Length) table, and compare the values against each other in order to get more information.

Does anyone have any methods for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out

Essentially, the classifier is a set of 4 values, the apriori probabilities, the mean and standard deviations of each of the probabilities, the different classes, and the original call.

Each of those values is a nested list with one item, and if you keep on delving into the individual lists you can get at the individual items, including the individual probability matrices, and work from there. The first value of each is the mean, and the second is the standard deviation. From there you can pull whatever data you want, and edit to your heart's extent.